# I am getting horizontal scrolling responsive issue in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, wordpress

I am getting horizontal scrolling issue in iPhone. I developed a website in WordPress. and also it getting problem in mobile phone UC browser how can I fix the problem.

Comment: you must provide more information : what is the issue more specifically ? what did you try ? can you share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to get a proper answer without looking at the site but what I usually do is use the component inspector from Chrome to locate any html elements that are created outside of the 320 px limit you have on iPhones and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information.

However, as a dirty, quick fix, try:

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That is indeed a dirty fix and it should never be used sitewide. You will most likely end up hiding content from your website. (Though I get it that OP's question is unprecise and this is the only answer at this time, it's still bad practice and will make maintenance harder.)